# How to implement that class component into a functional component using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a sign up form that have multiple fields, FirstName, Last Name, Email and Password:

code:

```
class Sign Up extends Component {
  state={
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
   }

   handleChange(e){
     this.setState({
       [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
   }
   return (
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <h5>Sign Up</h5>

          <div className="input-field">
              <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="firstName" onChange={handleChange}/>
         </div>

         <div className="input-field">
             <label htmlFor="lastName"></label>
             <input type="text" id="lastName" onChange={handleChange}/ >
         </div>

         <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="email"></label>
            <input type="email" onChange={handleChange} />
         </div>

         <div className="input-field">
             <label htmlFor="password"></label>
             <input type="password" onChange={handleChange} />
         </div>

         <button className="btn pink z-depth-0 lighten-1 text-grey">Sign up</button>
     </form>
  )
```

}

I tried to convert that to a functional component, and all i could do in the part of state is this:

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
const [lastName, setLAstName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
```

and then setting a different function for each one to change the state instead of one function `handleChange` in class component:

```
const handleFirstNameChange = (e) => {
  setFirstName(e.target.value)
}

const handleFirstNameChange = (e) => {
  setLastName(e.target.value)
}

const handleEmailChange= (e) => {
  setEmail(e.target.value)
}

const handlePasswordChange= (e) => {
  setPassword(e.target.value)
}
```

This is much verbose, Is there a way to implement the same stuff in classical component using hooks??

Comment: This will helps you to https://react-hook-form.com/

Comment: Thank you, just 34 sec of what i need, but is there a way without libraries?? @Kalhan.Toress

Comment: Nice to know this package @Kalhan.Toress thanks for sharing ! About doing it without libraries, well see my answers, this is the same thing, what you did also do the same thing but works with id (better to works with name as in the package, not much changes)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to split your state into multiple one when working with functional component, especially when working with a form the way you do, you can just do as follow :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';


const SignUp = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
   })

   const handleChange =(e) => {
     e.persist();
     setState(prevState => ({
       ...prevState,
       [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    }));
   }

   const handleSubmit = () => {
     console.log(state);
   }

   return (
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <h5>Sign Up</h5>

          <div className="input-field">
              <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="firstName" onChange={handleChange}/>
         </div>

         <div className="input-field">
             <label htmlFor="lastName">Last name</label>
             <input type="text" id="lastName" onChange={handleChange}/ >
         </div>

         <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" onChange={handleChange} />
         </div>

         <div className="input-field">
             <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
             <input type="password" id="password" onChange={handleChange} />
         </div>

         <button className="btn pink z-depth-0 lighten-1 text-grey">Sign up</button>
     </form>
  )
}

render(<SignUp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I just added missing id for email and assword jsx node, and changed the state to use useState, but kept the shape you defined in the class component before. This way you don't have much to change to make it work as before.

See [this repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-695prw?file=index.js)

Comment: This is the first time to know that i can use setState in a functional component, Thanks

Comment: @CodeEagle You can't use class based component `setState` in a functional one. It's just that the react `useState` hook has been instantiate with `[state, setState]`

Comment: @CodeEagle keep in mind that this is the setState that I choose, not the one you know from class component ! I mean, i cound name it `setWhateverYouWant`, this is just a local variable receiving a function that allow you to set your state. For example : `const [something, setSomething] = useState('defaultState')` and then using `setSomething('newState');` works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Just store an object in your `React.usState`:

```js
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
   });
```

And then use the same logic for your `handleChange` function:

```js
function handleChange(e) {
  setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.id]: e.target.value })
}
```

Comment: @CodeEagle No problem if it solve your problem pls don't forget to validate the answer 

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a useReducer:

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

const SignUp = () => {
  function reducer(currentState, newState) {
    return { ...currentState, ...newState };
  }

  const [{ firstName, lastName, email, password }, setState] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      password: ""
    }
  );

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("firstName: ", firstName);
    console.log("lastName: ", lastName);
    console.log("email: ", email);
    console.log("password: ", password);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h5>Sign Up</h5>

      <div className="input-field">
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={firstName}
          id="firstName"
          onChange={e => setState({ firstName: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="input-field">
        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={lastName}
          id="lastName"
          onChange={e => setState({ lastName: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="input-field">
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={e => setState({ email: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="input-field">
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={e => setState({ password: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>

      <button className="btn pink z-depth-0 lighten-1 text-grey">
        Sign up
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-margulis-wz8ge